# Criando propriedades, sumário e cores personalizadas para Métodos e Tipos

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-basic-6, cores

Tem algum jeito ou atributo que coloca numa Classe, Método, Estrutura ou qualquer outra coisa que muda a cor dele? Exemplo da função `CType`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que ela é colorida, e seus argumentos em vez de ficar `CType(Expression, TypeName) As Type` fica `CType(<expression>, <typename>) As <result>`

Eu criei um método chamado `GetTypeDynamic`, e gostaria de definir uma cor meio azulada, ou categorizar-lo como uma Keyword. Como ele fica no **Visual Studio 2015**:

[image]

**Eu já criei suas documentações XML**, então nem fale de usar `'''<summary>`!

E Gostaria de deixar-lo assim: (*Imagem simulada, não é real*)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar o **Visual Studio SDK**, mas não consigo utilizá-lo nem instalá-lo no meu PC

Comment: Na verdade se alguém responder e tiver voto, vai ficar automaticamente com metade da recompensa :D Eu fiquei curioso pra saber por que você quer isso. A mim não parece ter nenhuma importância a cor do texto. É bacana ter algumas cores porque facilita a leitura, mas a ponto de precisar que uma determinada função tenha uma cor específica... Não consigo imaginar a utilidade.

Comment: Talvez declarando uma função interna teria como, não como fazer isso, o meu Visual Studio 2015 não fica nada Vermelho nem Roxo, onde você modificou isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe nada que faça isso. Nem nenhum dos plugins que conheço (alguns pagos) fazem exatamente isso.

Para poder escolher a cor de cada método individualmente, o único jeito, é criar um plugin para isso, como você começou a fazer.

Precisaria manter uma lista dos membros, e uma UI para escolher a cor de cada um.

Comment: Você realmente precisa disso? Seria um projeto interessante. Mas acho que as soluções disponíveis são bastante boas, mesmo que não tenham ESSA capacidade.

Comment: Não sei, qualquer forma de mudar a cor, mesmo de não ser de Keyword iria ajudar.